# XML Risks and Mitigations

Tags: xml, security, text, xsd

What are the risks of using XML?

What are the risks of:

- unused namespaces
- hidden markup
- exponential regular expressions
- expontially expanding entities
- unvalidated namespace and namespace prefixes

What are the ways to mitigate the risks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I conducted a 1-day course on "XML Risks and Mitigations."

The material for the course may be found here:

http://www.mitre.org/work/tech_papers/2013/13_2445/

Comment: "Link-only" answers are not encouraged on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/155793. The link in the answer does not take you to the paper. The correct link is http://www.mitre.org/publications/technical-papers/xml-risks-and-mitigations.